# Undefined property: View::$Js

Tags: cakephp

Getting this. Site works fine locally, but up on production server I get this error.

cakephp verion 1.3

Production: php 5.3.3-7+squeeze7
Dev: 5.3.3-7+squeeze3

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Js [APP/views/layouts/default.ctp, line 31]
Code | Context

include - APP/views/layouts/default.ctp, line 31
View::_render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 736
View::renderLayout() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 494
View::render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 440
Controller::render() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 909
ErrorHandler::_outputMessage() - CORE/cake/libs/error.php, line 458
ErrorHandler::missingComponentFile() - CORE/cake/libs/error.php, line 415
Object::dispatchMethod() - CORE/cake/libs/object.php, line 112
ErrorHandler::__construct() - CORE/cake/libs/error.php, line 125
Object::cakeError() - CORE/cake/libs/object.php, line 201
Component::_loadComponents() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/component.php, line 216
Component::init() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/component.php, line 78
Controller::constructClasses() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 483
CakeErrorController::__construct() - CORE/cake/libs/error.php, line 52
ErrorHandler::__construct() - CORE/cake/libs/error.php, line 90
Object::cakeError() - CORE/cake/libs/object.php, line 201
Component::_loadComponents() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/component.php, line 216
Component::init() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/component.php, line 78

Fatal error: Call to a member function writeBuffer() on a non-object in /var/www/website.local/views/layouts/default.ctp on line 31
```

Line 31 is

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('cache'=> true));
```

I have in app_controller.php

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

        var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session','Js','Javascript');
        var $components = array(
                        'Session',
                        'RequestHandler',
                        'DebugKit.Toolbar'
                );
}

?>
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a component file:

```
ErrorHandler::missingComponentFile() - CORE/cake/libs/error.php, line 415
```

You may want to explore that error first, and then see if it fixes your other issue.

Comment: In fact, what is happening is you are probably trying to display an error view (due to the missing component) and since the AppError skirts the AppController, your JsHelper is not getting loaded. Thus the error is being thrown

Comment: ok, the file is there, can you tell what is throwing the error?

Comment: First of all, what controller/action are you trying access when you get this error? Check the components loaded for that controller, not necessarily the ones loaded in app_controller.php. Make sure all those are there and spelled correctly. On the other hand, you may want to put some debug in the CORE/cake/libs/error.php file at line 415 to see WHAT component file is throwing the error. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: add this before line 415 in error.php: debug( $file ); die; - that will tell you the file that is triggering that error.